# expression not callable => ts error in Pinia getters, what it means?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

[image]

I just started a Nuxt 3 project with Pinia and I don't understand the error in the **items.find** ⇒ which is:

> This expression is not callable. Translation: I can't call this expression because I can't call it like a function.

here's the code:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export interface Todo {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    done: boolean;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
}

export interface TodoState {
    items: Todo[] | undefined[];
}

const state = (): TodoState => ({
    items: [],
});

const getters = {
    getById: (state:TodoState) => (id:string) => {
        return state.items.find(item => item.id === id);
    } 
}

const actions = {}

export const useTodoStore = defineStore('todoStore',{
    state,
    getters,
    actions
})
```

What is wrong here & what would be the correct approach?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] (what does the `TodoState` type look like?) with code expressed as text not as a picture of text.

Comment: code was missing, my apologies.

Comment: The code differs from what you have on the screenshot. There's no type for `(state)`. Don't define `getters`, etc as separate variables because this prevents a store from inferring types.

Comment: The compiler is trying to tell you that applying `item => item.id === id` to a possible `undefined[]` is not possible.

Comment: @WiktorZychla In this case the error would be different, but this is a problem either.

Comment: I removed the undefined[ ] and it's working fine, also removed the getters const. Thanks!

Comment: @EstusFlask: for the current version of the code the compiler says `This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.` Not sure how OP got their error message. (the error message is of course caused by `find` inferred as a union type of incompatible function types).

Comment: This behavior is controlled by your typescript settings (`tsconfig` file). The option to check against undefined/nulls is `strictNullChecks`. If you don't want this check, you can disable it. https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks